# How to find the automorphism group of the graph mentioned in the question?

Tags: graph-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

*Hi, this is my 2nd question in this site. If it is not up to the mark, please do let me know, I will surely try to improve.*

The problem is from Graph Theory, specially *Automorphism Group.*
I know that the Automorphism Group of the complement of the complete graph $\overline{K}_n$  is isomorphic to $S_n$, the symmetric group on $n$ symbols.

Also the Automorphism Group  of the path graph $P_4$  will be $\{I,(1,4)(2,3\}$ which isomorphic to $S_2$.

[image]

My problem is a bit tricky where I am stuck:

**Problem:**
Let $G$ be a graph  such that  $G$ is made of $4$ components $G_1,G_2,G_3,G_4$ where $G_1=\overline{K}_2,G_2=\overline{K}_3,G_3=\overline{K}_4,G_4=\overline{K}_5$, i.e. $G$ can be obtained from $P_4$ in the following way:

The vertex *1* in $P_4$ is replaced by $G_1=\overline{K}_2$, the vertex *2* in $P_4$ is replaced by $G_2=\overline{K}_3$, the vertex *3* in $P_4$ is replaced by $G_3=\overline{K}_4$, the vertex *4* in $P_4$ is replaced by $G_4=\overline{K}_5$.
All the vertices of $\overline{K}_2$ are adjacent to all the vertices of $\overline{K}_3$, all the vertices of $\overline{K}_3$ are adjacent to all the vertices of $\overline{K}_4$, and all the vertices of $\overline{K}_4$ are adjacent to all the vertices of $\overline{K}_5$.

*Find the *automorphism* group of $G$ and its order.*

**My try**: I understand that the *automorphism* group of $G_1$ is isomorphic to $S_2$,
the *automorphism* group of $G_2$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, the *automorphism* group of $G_3$ is isomorphic to $S_4$,  and the *automorphism* group of $G_4$ is isomorphic to $S_5$. Also the *automorphism* group of $P_4$ is isomorphic to $S_2$.
I also understand that the blocks $G_1,G_2,G_3,G_4$ follow the adjacency criterion as in $P_4$.

But I am stuck on how to find the *automorphism* group of $G$ from here.
I require some help from you all. I am looking forward to some responses from all the learned experts available in MSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertices in $G_1,G_2,G_3,G_4$ are characterized by having degrees $3,6,8,4$, respectively. Hence any automorphism must permute vertices only within each $G_i$. This makes the automorphism group a subgroup of $S_2\times S_3\times S_4\times S_5$. On the other hand, *any* permutation of $G_1$ alone (or $G_2$ alone or …) turns out to be an automorphism, hence the group is indeed $S_2\times S_3\times S_4\times S_5$.